# A callback function with C linkage required from C++

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety, singleton, pthreads

Consider a following C++ singleton implementation, using pthread_once for 
thread safe initialization:

```
class MySingleton
{
public:
     static MySingleton* Instance();

protected:
     MySingleton() {};
     static void InitOnce();

private:
    static MySingleton* instance;
};


MySingleton* MySingleton::instance = NULL;

pthread_once_t singleton_once_control = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

MySingleton* MySingleton::Instance()
{
     pthread_once(&singleton_once_control, &InitOnce);
     return instance;
}

void MySingleton::InitOnce()
{
     instance = new MySingleton;
}
```

The problem is that pthread_once needs the callback function to have C-linkage.
(Okay, it is just a compiler warning and in the environment I am testing this
the code works cause C and C++ function call conventions are binary compatible)

But is there any good pattern for a real cross platform solution? You can create a C-linkage wrapper function but it cannot be part of the class and hence call the private init function InitOnce.

Any solution that avoids making the InitOnce public?

P.S. Yes, singletons are bad. Lets not make this about that...

Answer (score 4):

Make `InitOnce` a friend function instead, and give it `extern "C"` linkage.

Comment: A C-linkage function cannot be a friend... but of course this can worked around by adding yet another wrapper.

     extern "C" phtreadOnceCallback() { InitOnce(); }

Comment: @enomem: Is that so? Could you point me to the section in the standard that deals with that? C++ never stops surprising me.

Comment: @enomem: From my reading of the standard, I'm guessing that if you forward declare the friend function you can give it C linkage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this should be a problem. For `static` member functions this is only a question about name mangling and nothing else. Since all your code is C++ it will always be consistent. The only thing syntatic thing here is that in C, functions without parameters are declare with a `(void)` parameter list. I think this is usually deprecated for C++ (since unnecessary) but you could try if this silences the warning that you get.